# Mobility of coordinate complex ions

Tags: electrochemistry

Conductivity of ions depend on mobility of ions, but I doubt if a Coordinate complex formed can affect the mobility of that ion.
Let's say we have AgNO3 dissolved in Ammonia water. How can we compare mobility and Ion  Transport number of Ag+ in Water and in NH3-water, so that {Ag(NH3)2}+ complex is formed.
I think Mobility is decreased due to complex formation.

Comment: Consider the implicit coordination of $\ce{H2O}$ in both $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}$ as  $\ce{[Ag(H2O)_n]+}$ and $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2(H2O)_{n-2}]+}$.